# How can I add an image to every row in a TableView with JavaFX using labda expressions?

Tags: image, javafx

I have this initialize methode:

```
@FXML
private void initialize() {

    tituloColumna.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue()
            .tituloProperty());
    imagenColumna.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue()
            .imagenProperty());

    // Manejar evento DobleClick y Enter sobre una Receta para mostrar-la
    tablaRecetas.setOnMousePressed((event) -> {
        if (event.isPrimaryButtonDown() && event.getClickCount() == 2) {
            manejarEditarReceta();
        }
    });
    tablaRecetas.setOnKeyPressed((event) -> {
        if (event.getCode() == KeyCode.ENTER) {
            manejarEditarReceta();
        }
    });

}
```

And I need to change the String path of "imagen" of the second column to an image, in order to show both, a name and an image at the same row.

The code I like to link with lambda expresion:

```
public class ListaRecetasCelda extends TableCell<String,Receta>{

private ImageView view = new ImageView();

 @Override
 protected void updateItem(Receta item, boolean empty) {
    super.updateItem(item, empty);
    if (item != null) {
        view.setImage(item.getFoto());
        setGraphic(view);
        //setText(item.getNombre());
    } else {
        //setText(null);
        setGraphic(null);
    }
 }

}
```

Comment: Can you post the model class that is used to represent the rows of the table? (At least the relevant parts of it.)

Comment: `public class ListaRecetasCelda extends ListCell<Receta>{

 private ImageView view = new ImageView();

 
 
 @Override
 protected void updateItem(Receta item, boolean empty) {
  super.updateItem(item, empty);
  if (item != null) {
   view.setImage(item.getFoto());
   setGraphic(view);
   //setText(item.getNombre());
  } else {
   //setText(null);
   setGraphic(null);
  }
 }

}` here the class I'm trying to use to make the image objects

Comment: Sorry, I can't. There is only 2 columns in the Table. Is a table of recipes. The first column contains the name, and the second should contain an image of it. I'm trying to solve it using a RecipeImageCell class, to define each Image Object to be represented on each cell (of the column), but I can't link this images with the cells.

Comment: Can you edit your question to include the code, instead of putting it in the comment. Anyway, I wanted the model class, not a `ListCell` class. (The class that defines the `imagenProperty()` method in your current code.)

Comment: I edited the question, sorry @James_D